# How this where generic type constraint work?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I'm studying generic where constraint and I bumped into this and get stuck. I've tried replicating the code by my own classes but I get "Inconsistent inaccessibility".

```
//this is the reference study class
public class MainView<T> : System.Windows.Window where T : INotifyPropertyChanged, new(){}

//my own
interface ITest{}

class B : ITest
{
    public B()
    {

    }
}

public class MyClass<T> : B where T : ITest, new()
{

}
```

I couldn't figure this out. What is there in the reference study class? How can I do the same signature with my own defined classes and interface?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I didn't know my problem was about access modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how your `ITest` interface and `B` class don't have an explicit access modifier; when one is not provided the default is `internal` (for Top-level types), and you are implementing them in your `MyClass` class which is `public` (which is more accessible than `internal`, therefore, the compiler error). The solution is to change the access modifier of your types to `public` in this case, or alternatively, make your `MyClass` class `internal` instead of `public`.

```
 //my own
public interface ITest{}

public class B : ITest
{
    public B()
    {

    }
}

public class MyClass<T> : B where T : ITest, new()
{

}
```

More info about access modifiers can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels